# I need a LINQ query that formats my XML data as CSV data

Tags: xml, linq, csv, lambda, expression

The xml is the below format :

```
<categories>
  <category>Find product</category>
  <category>Shopping</category>
</categories>
```

I need a LINQ query ( lambda expression) that returns the results in the following format :

categories = Find product,Shopping

Comment: I feel like a [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28VS.100%29.aspx) wrapped around a [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) would be the best-answer.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like:

```
var categories = doc.Descendants("category") // Find "category" elements
                    .Select(x => (string) x); // Select the string value

// In .NET 4
string joined = string.Join(",", categories);

// In .NET 3.5 (fewer overloads for Join)
string joined = string.Join(",", categories.ToArray());
```

Comment: Was just wrapping up my code, beat me to it. (Kudos for showing .NET 3.5/4 overload, too.

Comment: How can it be written using the from clause ?